# Bold text in a Windows 8 Live Tile

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, live-tile

Is it possible to style text in a Live Tile?

I find that the large text is too large, but I would still like to have a distinguishable header.

Comment: It should be possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm surprised this has been closed as not a real question. I have been using the tile templates, as Jim O'Neil referenced, but I would like to customize them further, in this case by bolding some text. I have not seen any mention in any MSDN docs about this, however, which is why I ask the hivemind. Looks like Jim has answered my question very straightforwardly.

Comment: I agree with @mztan.  Seems like a legitimate question to me (especially since i landed here from googling the exact same thing pretty much)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's a number of [tile templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761491.aspx) to pick from; if none of those meets your needs you could generate an image and use that as the source.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1):

Use Expression Blend you will can do it

Comment: I don't think that is how displaying live tiles is implemented.